# Crash on hiding View

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a search bar at the top of a listview and there is an action button which toggles the visibility of the search bar...

The search bar is shown correctly, however when I hide it the app crashes. This is the code to toggle the view...

```
/**
 * Show / Hide the search box
 */
private void toggleSearch()
{

    //in the instance there are not customers...a crash will occur when searching
    if(customers.length > 0)
    {
            if(searchVisible)//hide the search bar
            {               
                searchFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Log.i("SEARCH", "HIDDEN");

                searchVisible = false;

                Log.i("SEARCH", "BOOLEAN SET");

                resetList();

                Log.i("SEARCH", "LIST RESET?");
            }
            else//show the search bar
            {                   
                searchFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                searchVisible = true;
            }
        }

}
```

and here is the LogCat output...

```
11-18 11:33:22.483: I/SEARCH(1591): SHOWN
11-18 11:33:22.493: D/audio_hw_primary(183): select_devices: out_snd_device(4: headphones)     in_snd_device(0: )
11-18 11:33:22.753: D/audio_hw_primary(183): out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(0: deep-buffer-playback) kvpairs: routing=4

11-18 11:33:24.473: I/SEARCH(1591): HIDDEN

11-18 11:33:24.473: I/SEARCH(1591): BOOLEAN SET

11-18 11:33:24.473: I/SEARCH(1591): LIST RESET?

11-18 11:33:24.473: D/AndroidRuntime(1591): Shutting down VM

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591): Process: evans.louis.firstdroid, PID: 1591

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:392)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2289)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1914)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1111)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1293)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)

11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)

11-18 11:33:24.483: W/ActivityManager(609):   Force finishing activity evans.louis.firstdroid/com.firsthosted.firstdroid.CustomerList
```

any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT: here is resetList() as requested

```
/**
 * Revert the ListView to it's original order
 */
private void resetList()
{
    try
    {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_container, R.id.name, customers);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter); 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Library.errorHandler("resetList", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: is searchFrame initialized?

Comment: @A.S. Yep. In the onCreate. Also in the onCreate I have already called searchFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE). This is what is confusing me...

Comment: Please share the method resetList()

Comment: is there any TextView in Your code? ... Check this error line "11-18 11:33:24.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1591): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference"

Comment: @Anilkumar There is an EditText but when I call setText() it works fine

Comment: Does layout/listview_container.xml contain a `TextView` (or its derivative) with `R.id.name`?

Comment: Use `searchFrame.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` instead of `searchFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE)` to hide your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just spotted my mistake in resetList()

I have...

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_container, R.id.name, customers);
```

and it should have been ...

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_text, R.id.name, customers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your calling setText on an element that is null, I'm assuming your calling the .setText method outside of your if statement.